# Memory usage of List vs Generator seems almost same. why?

Tags: python-3.x, memory, generator, profiler

I have the following python code. I am trying to understand python generators. If my understanding is correct the `print_list` will take much more memory than `print_generator`. I am using memory profiler to profile the two functions below.

```
from memory_profiler import profile
import logging


my_list = [i for i in range(100000)]

my_generator = (i for i in range(1000000))


@profile
def print_generator():
    try:
        while True:
            item = next(my_generator)
            logging.info(item)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    finally:
        print('Printed all elements')


@profile
def print_list():
    for item in my_list:
        logging.info(item)
        pass


logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')


print_list()

print_generator()
```

The result of the profiling is pasted below.

Memory usage for the generator.

```
 Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
10     23.0 MiB     23.0 MiB           1   @profile
11                                         def print_generator():
12     23.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       try:
13     23.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           while True:
14     23.0 MiB -26026.5 MiB     1000001               item = next(my_generator)
15     23.0 MiB -26026.5 MiB     1000000               logging.info(item)
16     23.0 MiB     -0.1 MiB           1       except StopIteration:
17     23.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           pass
18                                             finally:
19     23.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           print('Printed all elements')
```

Memory usage for the list

```
 Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
22     23.0 MiB     23.0 MiB           1   @profile
23                                         def print_list():
24     23.0 MiB      0.0 MiB      100001       for item in my_list:
25     23.0 MiB      0.0 MiB      100000           logging.info(item)
26     23.0 MiB      0.0 MiB      100000           pass
```

The memory usage for the list and the generator seems almost idendical.

So what am I missing here?. Why is generator using less memory?

Comment: Try initializing the list and generator inside each respective method. The list is initialized and in-memory during the execution of both profiled methods.

Comment: Why the negative marking ?